# Pandas colormap with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Pretty new to pandas and matplotlib and having trouble getting colormaps to work when using groupby.

Here is my test;

```
x=[]
for i in range(5):
   for j in range(9):
        x.append({'time':datetime(2013,1,1+i), 'col1':chr(ord('A')+j), 'col2':chr(ord('Z')-j), 'value':100+i*j})
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df=df.set_index('time')
df
```

Builds this dataset;

```
              col1 col2  value
time                       
2013-01-01    A    Z    100
2013-01-01    B    Y    100
2013-01-01    C    X    100
2013-01-01    D    W    100
2013-01-01    E    V    100
2013-01-01    F    U    100
2013-01-01    G    T    100
2013-01-01    H    S    100
2013-01-01    I    R    100
2013-01-02    A    Z    100
2013-01-02    B    Y    101
2013-01-02    C    X    102
2013-01-02    D    W    103
2013-01-02    E    V    104
2013-01-02    F    U    105
2013-01-02    G    T    106
2013-01-02    H    S    107
2013-01-02    I    R    108
2013-01-03    A    Z    100
2013-01-03    B    Y    102
2013-01-03    C    X    104
2013-01-03    D    W    106
2013-01-03    E    V    108
2013-01-03    F    U    110
2013-01-03    G    T    112
2013-01-03    H    S    114
2013-01-03    I    R    116
2013-01-04    A    Z    100
2013-01-04    B    Y    103
2013-01-04    C    X    106
2013-01-04    D    W    109
2013-01-04    E    V    112
2013-01-04    F    U    115
2013-01-04    G    T    118
2013-01-04    H    S    121
2013-01-04    I    R    124
2013-01-05    A    Z    100
2013-01-05    B    Y    104
2013-01-05    C    X    108
2013-01-05    D    W    112
2013-01-05    E    V    116
2013-01-05    F    U    120
2013-01-05    G    T    124
2013-01-05    H    S    128
2013-01-05    I    R    132
```

If I plot it as normal the last few items are the same colour;

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['value'].plot()
plt.legend()
```

http://postimg.org/image/cta2pa76f/

If I try a colourmap it doesn't seem to work;

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['value'].plot(colormap='jet')
plt.legend()
```

http://postimg.org/image/8y6ompo0n/

If I try `'Blues'` it's even worse with all white lines on a white background.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sort of does work, but because you're plotting from a `GroupBy`, each group (containing 1 column) gets plotted after each other, but on the same axes. This single column gets the first color from the selected `colormap`.

To get the colormap to work, you need multiple columns, then each column gets a different color from the colormap.

You could move 'col1' and 'col2' to the index and then unstack them. This assumes you only have one (col1, col2) combination per timestamp. For your original `df`:

```
df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'], append=True, inplace=True)
df.unstack(['col1', 'col2']).xs('value', axis=1).plot(colormap='jet')
```

[image]

Alternatively you could modify Matplotlibs `color cycle` with your selected colormap. Then your first plot would get the colors from the colormap. See:
http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/api/color_cycle.html

#### edit:

Using `pivot` is probably more appropriate then the unstacking as shown above:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),values='value', 
                    rows=['time'],cols=['col1', 'col2'])

df.plot(colormap='jet')
```

Comment: I also found it useful to use the optional parameter fill_value=0 so that missing rows could be plotted.